# JQuery Mobile - How to set Flip toggle switch slide Duration

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I'm trying to use the "[Flip Toggle Switch](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/switch/)" the jQuery Mobile library.
But I think the cursor animation is a bit too fast ...
Does anyone know a way to change the duration of the animation?
I have already looked inside the. js of jQuery and jQuery Mobile, but I found nothing.

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2szLS/) and code snippet :

```
<div data-role="content">
    <form action="#" class="foo" method="get">
        <p>
            <select id="modeLocation" class="ui-toggle-switch" data-role="slider">
                <option value="Courte"></option>
                <option value="Longue"></option>
            </select><span id="togshow">Courte</span>

        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#modeLocation").change(function () {
    type = $("#modeLocation").val();

    $('#togshow').text(type.toString());
});
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were looking at all wrong places :)

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/TTGbS/

**CSS:**

```
.ui-slider-handle-snapping {
    transition: left 470ms linear 0s !important;
}
```

Just change **`470ms`** to any time measured in miliseconds.

Comment: Ho! it was a CSS3 property ! I feel Stupid.. :D THanks you very Much [Gajorted](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1848600/gajotres)

Answer (score 0):

Have you want to add range slide in your site

If yes please use range slider in jquery mobile

For reference see below link

```
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/sliders/rangeslider.html
```